# Não consigo conexão com SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa noite, pessoal!
Alguém poderia me ajudar em relação ao um erro que estou tendo ao tentar me conectar ao SQL?
Eu abri um tópico anteriormente, mas ele foi fechado.

Estou há 02 dias tentando encontrar alguma solução, mas o erro ainda é o mesmo.

Não é possível conectar-se a JOSE.

> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o
> SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível.
> Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está
> configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Named Pipes
> Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL
> Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Erro: 2)

Comment: Não sei se posso adicionar fotos aqui, mas caso alguém precisa para facilitar algo, eu posso inserir.

Comment: bom, sem mostrar a string de conexão ou como está conectando fica bem difícil de ajudar... note que alguns tipos de conexões, como *"named pipes"* precisam ser habilitadas no servidor para se conectar... de qualquer forma não me parece uma pergunta para este site, talvez no https://dba.stackexchange.com/  faça mais sentido

Comment: de qualquer forma, consulte o FAQ da microsoft, lá tem um passo a passo para resolver a maioria dos problemas: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/resolve-connectivity-errors-overview

Answer (score -2):

```
 Boa Noite,
```

Esse erro geralmente ocorre devido à falta de configuração correta no arquivo de conexão com o banco de dados. Tenta essas opções:

Verificar se o nome do servidor e as credenciais de conexão estão corretos.

Verificar se o SQL Server está em execução e se o serviço de rede está habilitado.

Certifique-se de que a porta 1433 está aberta no firewall do servidor.

Tente usar o endereço IP do servidor ao invés do nome do servidor.

Certifique-se de que o protocolo TCP/IP esteja habilitado no SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Certifique-se de que o SQL Server Browser está habilitado no SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Tente reiniciar o serviço SQL Server.